# C# Compilation error in Visual Studio 2010 (Thrift 0.9.1 compilation)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation, thrift

I have downloaded Apache Thrift 0.9.1 from here: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageCSharp.  In Visual Studio 2010, I opened the .sln file in thrift/lib/csharp/src.

However, I am unable to build the solution.  I'm getting this error:

```
Error   3   The command "rmdir /s /q "C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\gen-csharp"
del /f /q "C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\ThriftImpl.dll"
SET OUTPUT_DIR=C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\
SET THRIFT_FILE=C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\\..\..\..\..\test\ThriftTest.thrift
for %%I in ("%OUTPUT_DIR%") do set SHORT_DIR=%%~fsI
for %%I in ("%THRIFT_FILE%") do set THRIFT_SHORT=%%~fs
"C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\\..\..\..\..\compiler\cpp\thrift.exe" --gen csharp -o %SHORT_DIR% %THRIFT_SHORT%
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /t:library /out:"C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\ThriftImpl.dll" /recurse:"C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\gen-csharp"\* /reference:"C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\thrift-0.9.1\lib\csharp\test\ThriftTest\..\..\src\bin\Debug\Thrift.dll"" exited with code 1.
```

I've looked in a number of places and am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the pre-build step of the `ThriftTest` project. If you have troubles with it, which can be difficult to debug, proceed as follows:

1. Remove the prebuild step stuff entirely from the C# project (Project Properties dialog, Build Events tab)
2. Compile the `\lib\csharp\src\Thrift.csproj` to produce the Thrift runtime assembly. Alternatively, consider including the `Thrift.csproj` project into the solution, which makes it easier to handle.
3. Open a command line, navigate to the appropriate folder and call `thrift.exe --gen csharp ThriftTest.thrift` to generate the code from the IDL. This will produce a new folder `gen-csharp` with a bunch of files in it. The `ThriftTest.thrift` IDL file is located in the `\test` folder.
4. Make sure the generated files from step 3 are included in the `ThriftTest` project
5. Build everything

Note that for step 3 you need the Thrift compiler (`thrift.exe`) in your path. This file is available as precompiled download on the [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org) web site, you don't need to build it on your own.

Comment: Thanks.  What is meant by "remove the prebuild step stuff entirely from the C# project"?  FYI, I have no settings file when I go to "Settings" in "Properties."

Comment: There is a tab "build events", even in the C# Express version. That's the one.

Comment: yes, that fixed it.  As for the thrift.exe step 3, that's in folder compiler/cpp right?  I'm getting [FAILURE:arguments:1] Could not open input file with realpath: ThriftTest.thrift when I run the command you specified.  Also, gen-csharp is 2 folders, in tutorial and tutorial/csharp.  Can't find a solution in either one.  So I'm still confused.

Comment: The compiler EXE can be found here http://thrift.apache.org/download/ as a download, or in the folder where it has been installed, if you build it on your own. The latter again depends whether you use MinGW or VC++. I'd recommend to use the download. Regarding gen-csharp: per default, the gen-csharp is generated within the current folder, from which you called thrift.exe If you could not open the input path then you're simply not in the right folder, or you have to specify a fully qualified file name for the *.thrift file.

Comment: I've downloaded the thrift-0.9.1.exe and put it in the main Thrift directory.  I don't get "realpath" but still have the error "Could not open input file...ThriftTest.thrift"

Comment: Assumed, your current folder is in the Thrift main folder, where the EXE is and subdisr named `lib` and `test` and `tutorial` and whatnot. Then you enter first a `cd test` command, followed by `..\thrift -gen csharp thrifttest.thrift`. Now you should get a folder `test\gen-csharp\Thrift\Test` with 29 *.cs files in it.

Comment: I tried that and still getting the same error.  FYI, I'm in Cygwin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46880/discussion-between-jensg-and-la-comadreja)